# Is "decades’ past" possessive?

Tags: possessives

I’m pretty sure I have this right; here's my sentence:

> There were a few random music friends from *decades’ past* there to see her, and she couldn’t be any prouder.

Do I have the apostrophe right?

Comment: Did you write the sentence?

Comment: It seems obvious from the question that he wrote it ans, no, there is no apostrophe required, as the OP is indicating plurality and not possessiveness.

Comment: As a UK native speaker, the phrase "music friends" grates on my ear. If they play music, then you can use "musical friends". If they are fans of the same genre, I am unsure how to phrase it elegantly. Another question, perhaps?  (hmmm, "there were a few random friends, united by their love of music, there...."? That still suonds clumsy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I have the apostrophe right?

No. There is no apostrophe.

> There were a few random music friends from *decades past* there to see her, and she couldn't be any prouder.

*Past* here basically means ["in the past."](http://grammarist.com/usage/passed-past/)

Answer (score 6):

No.

It would be if "decades" were a person called Decades, and the few random friends were from *his* past:

> ... friends from Decades' past ...

However, "past" here is an adjective modifying the word "decades." So, no apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, an apostrophe can indicate a missing letter ("Able was I, e'er I saw Elba"), or possessiveness ("The apostrophe's proper usage"), but **never** plurality, although this is a very common mistake.

I would also like to point out that "There were"  is past and "she couldn't be" is present.

Personally, I would match the tenses and write

> There were a few random music friends from decades' past there to see
>   her, and she couldn't ***have been*** any prouder

Comment: Except that it's "Able was I ere I saw Elba" ("ere" meaning before; the whole being written backwards).

Comment: Aagrgh!! You're correct, of course (+1)http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ere   Quick! Cover my panic. Find me an example of an apostrophe indicating a missing letter when not in penultimate position ...

Comment: You'd've been OK with this, wouldn't you? Although you can't say it mustn't be in penultimate position. (You also have "progressiveness" as a typo for "possessiveness", I think.)

Comment: Well done, you ne'er do well ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I had the present perfect there but stated it wrong. That will teach me for blogging after dark. And I agree that it's still awkward ...

Comment: Well, if you can explain how they are "music friends", maybe we can suggest an alternative. Or open a new question, if you wish.